# Constant coefficient and term differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Solve the following constant coefficient and term differential equation:

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}t} + 4y = 8 \quad \mbox{where} \quad y(0)=16$$

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Do you know that the general solution of $\frac{dy}{dt}=-4y$ is $Ae^{-4t}$?

2) We look for a particular solution of your DE. Easily you can notice that $y=2$ works.

3) So the general solution of the DE is $y=2+Ae^{-4t}$. Find $A$ such that $y(0)=16$.

**Another way 1:** Rewrite as $\frac{dy}{dt}=8-4y$, and then as $\frac{dy}{2-y}=4\,dt$.  Integrate. If you have done separation of variables, this will make sense. Otherwise it may not.

**Another way 2:**  Multiply both sides by the *integrating factor* $e^{4t}$. Notice that $e^{4t}y'+4e^{4t}y$ is the derivative of $e^{4t}y$. Now integrate. We get $e^{4t}y=\frac{8}{4}e^{4t}+C$.